# What qualifies as a token in CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror

In Codemirror cm.getTokenAt(pos) returns a token at the current cursor position. What exactly does a token mean?

For eg. When you look for a token in the line "System.out.println", it returns the token println, whereas when you search for a token in "System.out.", it return "."

Also is a token language dependent and different results are obtained for different languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A token is whatever the mode writer wants it to be. In the context of a codemirror mode, a token is a sequence of text that should be highlighted as a unit. A token is one "thing". That might mean one character (such as an opening or closing brace), or a function or variable name.

The token is completely dependent on the language mode, though most languages use the same rough definition for tokens (functions, variables, syntax characters, comments, etc)